# How to prove that $\sum \frac{1}{n^k}$ converges for $1<k<2$ without calculus?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, power-series

I'm teaching infinite sequences and series in a precalc class for the first time, and among other things, we've been thinking about:

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-k}$$
If we knew calculus, we could do an integral and show that this diverges for $k\le 1$, and converges for $k>1$. But we don't know calculus yet in my class! Rats.

So instead, I found [a nice algebraic proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Divergence) that this diverges for $k=1$ (and by comparison, for $k<1$). I also found [a nice algebraic proof](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9euTxoCC8Hk) that this converges for $k=2$ (and by comparison, for $k>2$).

But this still leaves us with the question of what happens between $k=1$ and $k=2$. My vague poking at the question, as well as some internet searching, hasn't turned up much.

So: how can we show, without using calculus or other fancy techniques, that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-k}$ converges for $k>1$? Is there a nice, simple proof?

Comment: If $\sum 1/k^n$ converges for some $n\ge2$ then so does $\sum 1/k^{n+1}$, because $1/k^{n+1}\le 1/k^n$ for all $k$.

Comment: The same argument used in your link to prove that $\sum 1/n$ diverges can be used to show convergence of $\sum 1/n^k$ for $k>1$. Instead of replacing the powers by the smallest in each group, replace by the largest.

Comment: @clathratus, the OP (using $k$ for $n$ and *vice versa*) made that point in the paragraph with the links, without the assumption that the exponent is an integer.

Comment: @conditionalMethod How did I never know this in my 40 year mathematical career! You should make that an answer.

Comment: @LeeMosher It is just Cauchy's condensation test's proof.

Comment: @conditionalMethod, thank you! That's perfect.

Answer (score 6):

We can prove that for $k>1$ the series converges proving by induction that

$$S_N=\sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n^k} \le1+\frac1{k-1}\left(1-\frac1{N^{k-1}}\right)$$

or, as an alternative, by [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test), that is

$$\sum 2^n a_{2^n}=\sum\frac{2^n}{(2^n)^k}=\sum \frac1{2^{n(k-1)}}$$

which converges by ratio test.